# How can I deal with 'str' object has no attribute '_meta' error on my django project

Tags: python, django, forms, model, attributeerror

I have django project that have a form to upload data which save at my database.
But there are some problems which I cannot deal with.
I try to find documentations to deal with problem, but I can't find which can help me.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth
from exam.functions.functions import handle_uploaded_file  
from django.http import HttpResponse
from exam.forms import Examinationform
from exam.models import Examination 
import json


# Create your views here.

def upload1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            main=[]
            exam = Examinationform(request.POST, request.FILES)      
            if exam.is_valid():
                for _file in request.FILES.getlist('fileexam'):
                    _file = request.FILES['fileexam']       #devide list of files.
                    filename = _file.name
                    main.append("filename")
                    handle_uploaded_file(_file)
                Examination.namefileexam = json.dumps(main)
                Examination.category = request.POST.get('category')
                try: 
                    Examination.notation = request.POST.get('notation')
                except AttributeError:
                    Examination.notation = ''
                try:
                    Examination.name = request.POST.get('name')
                except AttributeError:
                    Examination.name = ''
                Examination.save('self')
                exam = Examinationform()
                main.clear()
                return HttpResponse("File uploaded successfuly")  
    else:  
        exam = Examinationform()  
        return render(request,'uploadfileexam1.html',{'form':exam})
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms


class Examination(models.Model):
   namefileexam = models.TextField(null=True)
   notation = models.CharField(max_length=78, blank=True, null=True)
   category = models.CharField(max_length=25)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)`

    enter code here
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from exam.models import Examination
 

BOSS_CHOICES=(
    ('sheets', 'sheets'),
    ('contestexams', 'contestexams'),
    ('schoolexams', 'schoolexams'),
    ('others', 'others'),
    )

class Examinationform(forms.Form):
     fileexam = forms.FileField(label = 'เลือกไฟล์', required = True, widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
     notation = forms.CharField(label = 'หมายเหตุ', required = False, max_length=78)
     category = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'ประเภทของไฟล์', required = True, choices = BOSS_CHOICES)
     name = forms.CharField(label = ชื่อผู้อัปโหลด(ใส่ไว้ในเครดิต)', required = False, max_length=78)
```

When I submit, It show me AttributeError.
'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
I think this problem is form views.py. But I don't know what should I do.
Help me please

**Thank you for answers and sorry for my english skill**

Comment: `Examination.save('self')`?

Comment: How about using hasattr() to test for the attribute existance before trying to use it?